# GL_EXT_packed_pixels vs GL_APPLE_packed_pixels

Tags: macos, opengl

My application checks for `GL_EXT_packed_pixels` extension before using packed pixel formats such as `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_EXT`. On my MacBook, my code can't find this extension, despite that using packed pixel formats still appears to work.

OpenGL Extension Viewer seems to suggest that it has a special name on OS X:

[image]

What's the difference? Should I just check for either [`GL_EXT_packed_pixels`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/packed_pixels.txt) or [`GL_APPLE_packed_pixels`](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/extensions/apple_packed_pixels.html) when assessing if `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_EXT` is supported?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're checking for support for this in OS X in the first place? `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` went core in OpenGL 1.2 and you'd have to be dealing with an ancient PowerPC Mac in order for that version where 1.2 is relevant. You can pretty much assume 100% 2.1 compliance on any Intel Mac or newer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman *RDP sessions* do not support `GL_EXT_packed_pixels`.

Comment: That's an entirely different can of worms. If you're talking about an RDP connection to Windows, then the capability set has nothing to do with the OS X host and everything to do with the virtual head on the Windows machine. You wind up with the software implementation of OpenGL (GDI), which is limited to OpenGL 1.1. About the best you could really hope for is to get Mesa up and running, but performance is never going to be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXT_packed_pixels` has these definitions:

```
UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2_EXT         0x8032
UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4_EXT      0x8033
UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1_EXT      0x8034
UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_EXT        0x8035
UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2_EXT     0x8036
```

While `APPLE_packed_pixels` has these:

```
UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2         0x8032
UNSIGNED_BYTE_2_3_3_REV     0x8362
UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5        0x8363
UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV    0x8364
UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4      0x8033
UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4_REV  0x8365
UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1      0x8034
UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5_REV  0x8366
UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8        0x8035
UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV    0x8367
UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2     0x8036
UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV 0x8368
```

Comparing the two, `EXT_packed_pixels` is a subset of `APPLE_packed_pixels`, and the shared values are the same. Therefore, if `APPLE_packed_pixels` is supported, you can safely use all definitions from `EXT_packed_pixels`.

As your screen shot of the extension viewer already suggests, `GL_EXT_packed_pixels` has been core functionality since OpenGL 1.2. So in most cases, you should not have to test for any of these in the extension string. If you check the version first, and it's at least 1.2, you already know that the functionality is available. The test logic could look like this:

```
if (strcmp(glGetString(GL_VERSION), "1.2") >= 0 ||
    strstr(glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "_packed_pixels") != NULL)
{
    // supported
}
```